# Retrieving KeywordModel metadata inside component model of a nested category/keyword (DXA 2.0.3, Java)

Tags: dxa, dxa-2.0, java, keyword, metadata

I've been trying to retrieve the metadata value of extended entity of KeywordModel on DXA 2.0.3 with no luck.

My component is called **kennisitem** with the following schema:

[image: Kennisitem schema]

Kennisitem has a metadata field called **regeling**.
Regeling (CGH - Regeling) is a category that's created this way:

[image]

And this is the properties of one of **regeling** keywords.

[image]

As you can see, this keyword has **Thema Metadata** as metadata schema selected. The schema itself is pretty simple:

[image]

This schema contains a field called **kleurvoorpagina** that points to other category which is called **Opmaak**, and this contains keywords that I can select when assigning property of **regeling**.

In Java, I made an entity model class of **Kennisitem** component

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@SemanticEntity("Kennisitem")
public class Kennisitem extends AbstractEntityModel {
    private List<Regeling> regeling;
}
```

and Regeling is a model class extending **KeywordModel**

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Data
@SemanticEntity("Regeling")
public class Regeling extends KeywordModel {
    @SemanticProperty("kleurvoorpagina")
    private String kleurvoorpagina;
}
```

The list of **Regeling** is populated, but the value of ***kleurvoorpagina*** is always *null*. What am I missing here? Both **Regeling** and **Kennisitem** are registered in module initializer.

Note: I tried to debug **KeywordConverter@convert** from dxa-tridion-provider and I can see that the metadata is in **KeywordWrapper** variable. However my **kleurvoorpagina** field is not populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for semantic mapping to work, your View Model types should map to your CM Schemas either implicitly (based on type name) or explicitly using `SemanticEntity` annotations.

In case of your Keyword Model, it has to map to the Keyword’s metadata Schema in CM. Since it’s a metadata Schema (and thus has no root element name), the mapping is done on the CM Schema’s title.

Your Keyword’s metadata Schema title is “Thema Metadata”. Therefore, the Keyword Model’s type name or `SemanticEntity` annotation should be `ThemaMetadata` (unless you would annotate the CM Schema with semantic type App Data, but let’s not go there).

For more info, see https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v12/GUID-C0AD6DCC-ED65-441F-B361-928A18B2896D

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem

Comment: You’re welcome. So, for clarity: `SemanticEntity` or `SemanticProperty` annotations which just repeat the name of the type/property are redundant.